# Why the assigned value is nil?

Tags: ios, string, null, swift3

I use oAuth for the users login.

```
func getUserInfoResponse(_ response: APIResponse!) {
    print("----------------------------------------")
    print("用户资料获取成功：")
    print(response.jsonResponse)
    //print(response.jsonResponse["figureurl_qq_2"])

    let accessToken = _tencentOAuth.accessToken
    let nickname    = response.jsonResponse["nickname"] as! String!
    let avatar      = response.jsonResponse["figureurl_qq_1"] as! String!
    let avatar2     = response.jsonResponse["figureurl_qq_2"] as! String!
    let urlString:String = "http://www.xxxxxx.com/cloud/app?openid=\(accessToken!)&nickname=\(nickname!)&avatar=\(avatar!)&avatar2=\(avatar2!)"
    self.wk = WKWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    let url = URL(string: urlString)!
    self.wk.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    self.view.addSubview(self.wk)

}
```

and `print(urlString)` is

> http://www.example.com/cloud/app?openid=xxxxxxx32D1E05D95E91881A15A8CDC75&nickname=
>   .&avatar=http://q.qlogo.cn/qqapp/101237639/90012AB5E745A1B10A6F5F4A14F0B48D/40&avatar2=http://q.qlogo.cn/qqapp/101237639/90012AB5E745A1B10A6F5F4A14F0B48D/100

when user login, , all the values have value except the url and get this error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

[image]

[image]

Why the url is nil, it has been assigned with value.  Sorry I'm new to ios and swift3.

Comment: You checked whether the address exists? Can you print `urlString` before create URL object
Pay particular attention to the parameters (openid, nickname, avatar, avatar2). Response can be fun

Comment: can you print `urlString` value on console?

Comment: @sweta.me yeah. here is the urlString http://www.xxxxxx.com/cloud/app?openid=Optional("xxxxxxxxxxx1E05D95E91881A15A8CDC75")&nickname=Optional("                       .")&avatar=Optional("http://q.qlogo.cn/qqapp/101237639/90012AB5E745A1B10A6F5F4A14F0B48D/40")&avatar2=Optional("http://q.qlogo.cn/qqapp/101237639/90012AB5E745A1B10A6F5F4A14F0B48D/100")

Comment: This --> "Optional(" in urlString is causing `let url = URL(string: urlString)` to be `nil` & you are trying to unwrap it by appending `!` at the end, which is causing crash...

Comment: And btw, accidentally clicking on the URL in your comment opened some NSFW things on my office machine :(

Comment: @sweta.me for security I've change the accesstoken and hostname of the url in the comment. sorry for this.

Comment: Never mind. Have you got it working?

Comment: @sweta.me I edit is accord as your comment, and edit the question here. it also not works and stop at the same place.  Thank you.

Comment: @KrisRoofe You need to encode the url, Check the answer given by Leo

Comment: @NiravD Yeah it works. Thank you. What the reason here?

Comment: @KrisRoofe Your nickname contains space and you cannot simply add space with url you need to encode it Also instead of creating url like this batter to use `URLComponents`, that will encode url for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode the url before use it

```
if let urlEncoded  = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed){
    let url = URL(string: urlEncoded)
}
```